# useEffect value not passing through props

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using a `useEffect` to call my backend, however I cannot pass the value through my component to another component. When doing a `console.log` on the `fileTypes` variable within my original component I can retrieve the data successfully, however once I have this data I want to pass it through as a `prop` to another component.

```
const [fileTypes, setFileTypes] = useState([]);
useEffect(() => {
  getLookupData('permittedFileType').then((data) => {
    setFileTypes(data);
  });
}, []);
console.log(fileTypes);
```

My `useEffect` which does log me back my data:

```
{fileTypes && fileTypes.length > 0 <Component fileTypes={fileTypes}/>}
```

Passing the fileTypes prop through into my new component:

```
const {  fileTypes, classes } = props;
```

However, when console logging out the above I receive `undefined`.

Comment: How are you accessing the props in your child component?

Comment: @Clarity as a console.log(fileTypes);

Comment: `{fileTypes && fileTypes.length > 0 <Component fileTypes={fileTypes}/>}` is missing one `&&` before component.

Comment: @Clarity sorry, my mistake this was a copy and paste error

Comment: alright, are you sure that the `data` you get from the api is defined?

Comment: @Clarity yes, within the useEffect i will receive back my array of fileTypes

Comment: Based on the code it shouldn't be possible that `fileTypes` is undefined in your child component since in that case that component shouldn't even be rendered.